# javascript inside php code

Tags: php, javascript

i have place javascript inside php code, like this
`<?php if(condition) { ?><script>do some scripting here</script><?php } ?>`
it works perfect when i run it in local.
but when i upload it to the server it doesnt run..
the javascript doesnt work.
Can anyone please help.
thanks,
Devan

Comment: Is the file extension for this code `.php`?

Comment: Please explain the behavior further. What is the behavior when it works, what is the behavior when it's not working. How are you running it. What type of server is involved, etc.

Comment: I think you're probably missing some braces here... `{}` around the HTML snippet will likely help things.

Comment: Post a link to where you've uploaded it.

Comment: @Austin: yes my file extension is .php

Comment: @Chris: what my code does is that, firstly my php code checks whether the device is mobile or not and if it is mobile it will do the script.

Comment: when i locally test my page it works perfect.But when i test it on the server it doesn't work.The thing i do is on detecting a mobile redirecting the page.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'm pretty sure you have to do either:

```
<?php if (condition) { ?>  ** script stuff ** <?php } ?>
```

or

```
<?php if (condition) : ?> ** script stuff ** <?php endif; ?>
```

(Your script has no scope on the `if` statement, although that could be a copy/paste error).

Second, it could be your script (perhaps one of the Javascript files such as jQuery isn't on your server).

Comment: i have done the coding as u mentioned in the first and also there is no file missing in my server because only this thing doesnt work the rest of the scripting works perfect.

Comment: @Devan - Can you confirm that the script text is actually in the source the client receives (i.e. through a view source or similar?). If so, can you confirm that the script doesn't rely on any other JS files than other scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is pretty vague...

Here's all the things I would review first :

- are you sure php runs on your distant server ?
- do you have anything on screen when running your script ?
- when you view the source code from the generated page : do you see your javascript code ?
- did you check for javascript error messages ?

Another batch of questions after the comments :)

- Did you try to change your JS code with a "basic" one, such as "alert('my code works');" ? (in order to see if your javascript code is triggered)
- If the basic alert code does not produce a popup, then you should see your browser's setup with javascript. It may not be enabled
- if it works (and you don't have any JS error messages) : try to place some more "alert" popups along your own code, in order to find where your code stops to work)

This will not provide you a direct answer to your problem, but will help you to find more details on your problem, and will help us find an answer

Comment: hi,> i have php running on my distant server. > yes on my screen instead of redirecting to the mobile page it shows the orginal page >when i view the source code from the generated page i can see the javascript code,