# Embedding Javascript inside PHP doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php

My problem is very similar to [javascript inside php code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932723/javascript-inside-php-code)

I am trying to embed Javascript code inside PHP. But Javascript code doesn't seem to work. My sample code is as below. I am trying to run is on my local XAMPP server. If i remove Java script code, rest of PHP code works perfectly fine.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include('connection.php');
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $emailID=$_POST['emailID'];
    $pwd=$_POST['pwd'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE uname = '$emailID' AND pwd = '$pwd'") or die(mysql_error());

if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error()))
{
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_info(fname, lname, uname, pwd, phone)VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$emailID', '$pwd', '$phone')") or die(mysql_error());
?>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            window.parent.modalWin.CallCallingWindowFunction(0, 'User registration successful');
        </script>   
<?php
        mysql_close($con);
}
else
{

?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("E-mail is already registered");
    </script>
<?php   
    header("location: registration.html");
}
?>
```

Comment: _"doesn't seem to work"_ - What does it do? Do you get a server-side error in the PHP? Does it serve the page to the browser and then you get a JS error in the browser console? Or...?

Comment: try replacing the script blocks with "User registration successful" and "E-mail is already registered". Do they appear on the page?

Comment: After some more debugging, i realized after the script, if i try to re-direct, the alert message doesn't come up. echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Alredy registered");</script>'; header("location: registration.html");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try directly in you php like this

```
<?php 


echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Data alert");</script>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, it works fine, but after the script, if i try to re-direct, the alert message doesn't come up.                      echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Alredy registered");</script>';
 header("location: registration.html");